# Python - Unit test - How to mock a connection string (postgres)

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

Hi I have a method on my main.py which basically receives a dataframe and connection string, I am sending this dataframe to sql database on PostgreSQL.

```
def connect_with_postgres(df_table,sql_conn):
    db = create_engine(sql_conn)
    conn=db.connect()
    #build a table and put the dataframe information into
    df_table.to_sql('table_name', con=conn, if_exists='replace', schema='schemaname', index=False)
    conn.close()
    print("The data has been stored into the database.")
```

Then on my unit test I am taking a csv with a sample of data and put it into variable on my mocks.py

```
with open('mocks/table.csv', 'r') as file:
    mock_table_csv = file.read()
    file.close()
```

And last one my unit test function:

```
def test_connect_with_postgres(self):
    conn_result = Mock()
    mock_conn.connect.return_value = conn_result
    mock_table = pd.read_csv(StringIO(mock_table_csv))
    output = connect_with_postgres(mock_table,conn)
```

But is trying to get a real connection string, shows me this

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Mock object
```

If I send a real conn string it works but the idea is to mock the connection string (fake one) and test that the function works, any idea how to make this happend?

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249876/16475089

Comment: Hi I already tried with that but shows me this error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0), and as I mentioned sending a real conn works. Also I am using SQL Alchemy